# How can I add style to message before send mail?

Tags: c#, email, customization

How Can I customization message before send mail in C#?
I want to break line in somewhere in text, or set specific font in message.
Can anyone help me?
pice of code:

```
SEPNA.BLL.Mail mail = new BLL.Mail();
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        Font boldfont = new Font("B Nazanin", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
        rtb.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
        rtb.Font = boldfont;
        SEPNA.DAL.DBMLs.COM_TbUser user = new SEPNA.DAL.Implementation.UsersDAL().GetUserByUserID(DisplayID);
        if (mailType == Types.WorkFlowMail.Mail)
        {
            switch (step)
            {
                case SEPNA.Types.FlowStep.PackageUpload:
                    rtb.Text = MessageBody.Replace("[DisplayName]", user.DisplayName).Replace("[ApplicationName]", AppName).Replace("[ActivityID]", activity).Replace("\n", new StringBuilder().AppendLine().ToString());
                    Subject = Subject.Replace("[ApplicationName]", AppName);
                    break;
```

Regards!

Comment: Please, show us your code and what you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Just send your mail as html:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("to_address");
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string htmlBody;

            htmlBody = "Write some HTML code here";

            mail.Body = htmlBody;

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
```

Comment: Credit for Google :)

Comment: I really like your `mail.To.Add("")`, I did not know this existed. I just used a string with `;` at the end of each email.

Answer (score 0):

MailMessage.IsBodyHtml

You can set to true

```
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{                       
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    IsBodyHtml = true // this property
})
```